Kotlin Gradle Multiplatform not producing nodejs artifact
I'm trying to write an app that does server side rendering of a kotlin react app. Here's a sample version of the app. It's written to renderBrowserApp/src/jsMain/kotlin/horcrux/browserapp/render/App.kt
package horcrux.browserapp.render

import react.create
import react.dom.html.ReactHTML.p
import react.dom.server.rawRenderToString

fun main() {
    println(rawRenderToString(p.create { +"hello" }))
}

Here's the build.gradle.kts for that subproject. I'm using Gradle version 8.0.2 and Kotlin multiplatform version 1.9.21.
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

val kotlinWrappersVersion: String = "1.0.0-pre.736"

kotlin {
    js {
        nodejs()
        binaries.executable()
    }

    sourceSets {
        jsMain.dependencies {
            implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin-wrappers:kotlin-react")
            implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin-wrappers:kotlin-react-dom")
            implementation(project.dependencies.enforcedPlatform("org.jetbrains.kotlin-wrappers:kotlin-wrappers-bom:$kotlinWrappersVersion"))
        }
    }
}

When I run ./gradlew renderBrowserApp:build I expect to see a Javascript files appear as an artifact in renderBrowserApp/build/dist. Instead the dist director isn't even created. Is there something I'm misconfiguring? The docs on the nodejs target for Kotlin multiplatform are sparse.

The setup looks fine to me.
Have a look in build/compileSync/js/main/productionExecutable/kotlin for the JS file to run in Node.
For good or for ill, if you want to do much beyond the basics with the Kotlin multiplatform Gradle plugin, you're going to need to be ready to dig around in its code to see what's going on.
